# Twitter api response inside a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, twitter

I've got an FB page tab app - basically a web page inside an iframe and gets displayed when a user clicks on the page tab.

Inside the web page I've got a Twitter button. I'm using Twitter's API to find out when the user has successfully tweeted. Here's the code I use for this:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    alert("tweet's ocured");
});
```

The thing is - if I view the page normally I'm receiving the `alert()` after a tweet. If I view it from Facebook it doesn't work.... It's as though Twitter's response is not getting passed to the page on Fb?

Additionally in my console I get the following warnings:

> TWITTER: Content Security Policy restrictions may be applied to your
>   site. Add  to supress
>   this warning.

.

> TWITTER: Please note: Not all embedded timeline and embedded Tweet
>   functionality is supported when CSP is applied.

.

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://giveaway-testing.herokuapp.com"
>   from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com". The
>   frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the
>   frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to
>   the same value to allow access.

.

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://platform.twitter.com" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://www.mysitehere.com". The frame
>   requesting access set "document.domain" to "twitter.com", but the
>   frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the
>   same value to allow access.

Has anyone dealt with these issues before? If so help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the "TWITTER" console messages add the following code to your page header:

```
<meta name="twitter:widgets:csp" content="on">
```

Use of the meta tag is explained at the bottom of the Twitter developer doc here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/widgets-meta-elements.

The other warnings relate to JavaScript's same-origin policy. The http://giveaway-testing.herokuapp.com in one of the warnings mentioned in your original post is no longer operational. Do you still have a version of the page to look at?